# Reading from many files in a loop and writing the read data from each file in another file in Python

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am making a script to read several files and copy the information from them to another file.

My initial script is supposed to read `.xlsx` files from a given directory, copy a certain part of a specific sheet in the file and paste it to another file. This is my code, which is working:

```py
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd
import numpy
data=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\bvi\Desktop\python 
   script\EMC_review_template_v10.xlsx',sheet_name='Test_Summary',skiprows=5,nrows=44,usecols='A:O')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df2=df.to_excel('try.xlsx',sheet())
print(df2)
```

When I tried to form a loop the problems began:

```py
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import pathlib
import os
path=(r"C:\Users\bvi\Desktop\files")
files = []
###r=root, d=directories, f = files
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        length=len(files)
        for i in range(length):
            print(filename[i])

data = pd.read_excel(r'path\filename[i]',sheet_name='Test_Summary', skiprows=5,nrows=44, 
    usecols='A:O')

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df2=df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\bvi\Desktop\result\summary.xlsx',sheet_name='EMC_review1')
print(df2, file)
```

I am struggling to create a loop which goes through the files in the directory. I would like to make the reading of files a function of the file name.

Comment: what's the error that you encountered?

Comment: Your code snippet lost its indentation, could you edit to make things clearer?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the pb comes from the double loop inside the `os.walk` loop. Try this:

```
path=(r"C:\Users\bvi\Desktop\files")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        print(filename)
        data = pd.read_excel(path+'/'+filename',sheet_name='Test_Summary', 
                             skiprows=5,nrows=44, usecols='A:O')
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df2=df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\bvi\Desktop\result\summary.xlsx',
                        sheet_name=filename)
```

If all your 'filename' are unique, this will combine the 'Test_summary' sheet from several xlsx files into a multi-sheet xlsx (one sheet per file). Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. The string filename is like [EMC_review1, EMC_review1]..etc in each of them I have the sheet "Test_Summary". I wanted to read  the columns from A to O from this sheet and do that for all the files then write the read array of data in one multisheet file. I tried your code in mine but I stumbled upon an error.

Comment: @Billana Vidova: Could you paste the error message, here ?

Comment: I managed to make it work but now everything is written in the same sheet in the output file..